# Namespace for class declaration in file executed at runtime

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I wrote a program to allow users to give me a class name and the file that defines that class like so:

```
    input = raw_input("Input the new classname with a space and then the file name defining the class")
    class_name, file_name = input.split(" ")
```

I then execute the file defining the class:

```
  execfile(file_name)
```

and try to create an instance of the newly defined class:

```
    d[k] = eval(new_class)(**d[k])
```

However this creates the following error:

```
    d[i] = eval(new_class)(**d[i])
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MeasureDay' is not defined
```

This is after I fed in the following class definition that was executed:

```
class MeasureDay:
    print("defining measureday")
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.day = kwargs.get('day', -1)
        self.measurement_value = kwargs('measurement_value', -1)

    def __str__(self):
        return "here is a custom defined string for MeasureDay"
```

I know the class definition was executed because I see the logged statement "defining measureday" as desired.

**What am I doing wrong? I am guessing this has to do with some namespace convention. Do I need to define a namespace when I define classes like so, and if so how would I do it. Otherwise, what is the problem?**

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you say `print(locals())` right after the execution, does it have anything that was defined in that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` and `execfile` are to be avoided, and are unnecessary here. `importlib.import_module` can import the module file from a string, and you can then use `getattr` to get the class for instantiation.

```
class_name, file_name = input.split(" ")
mod = import_module(file_name)
cls = getattr(mod, class_name)
d[k] = cls(**d[k])
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I wanted a way to do this without eval, but I didn't know what that was. Any tips on other ways to create instances of dynamically referenced classes without eval?